# How to set spinner in action bar for android application?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, uinavigationbar, android-spinner

I am using action bar for my application. I am getting my preview in device like this

[image]

My spinner didn't set properly. I added button as item in menu. My code is here... http://pastie.org/8482541

When i run in my device only it shows some what different.

[image]

How can i do this? Can any body help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i like variant A much more though..

Comment: Are Layouts A and B of different screens?

Answer (score 0):

try like this for each menu item you want

```
@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item1);
      item.getActionView().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(/*some color you need */));

      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

use this custom menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
         <item android:id="@id/item1"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/action_text"/>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

You need to take one button and set any image as its background.Then on click of the button call Spinner.performClick() to open the spinner.

Below is code to implement the same thing. In xml file:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/font"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/textsel" /> 

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="0dp"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="20dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="500dp"
    android:paddingTop="2sp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" >
</Spinner>
```

In Java class:

```
  Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);

  Button typetext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.font);      


  typetext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        spin.performClick();

    }
});
```